# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities IOS

Tags: ios

I have received a rejected from Apple Store.[image: my info.plist is in the picture]   I did not have a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities set.My app
can both install on the iphone and ipad.So I feel uncertain what can i do.

We were unable to install the app on iPhone and iPad. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

Comment: Hello,I only have GoogleService-Info.plist. it contains only the information Property List.

Answer (score 0):

Check your info.plist of your target.

[image]

If you are supporting you project for iPhone 4s and onward then include armv7 and Armv7s supported from iPhone 5, 5c, 5S, iPod touch-5, iPad-4, iPad Air. Armv7s designed for A6 processor. Supporting from IOS6+. It's also support for 64-bit coding but processing get slow in those devices with armv7s instruction set.. Arm64 devices are from Iphone 5s, iPad Air. That's related to A7 Processor

Comment: Vaild Architectures is armv7 arm64. deployment target is 8.0.  i think it can support all the devices.

Comment: Yes but @LabsPanda he's saying it looks like you've accidentally _deleted_ the "Required device capabilities" key.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1397/_index.html   Do not add a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key unless you actively need to restrict installation of your application based on the availability or lack of availability of a device feature.    Does it mean we do not need it.I have submited my app many times, and never have the "Required device capabilities" key before.

Comment: You only need it if you want to restrict installations to certain hardware. If you don’t, you should send a message to the reviewer who thought you did for some reason.

Comment: Good point. I've written back to the reviewers in the past, with good results. If you think they're wrong, ask them about what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. I have written back. the reviewers accept it this time